# Why am I facing problem in plotting pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a pie chart for all the 'Trend' to know about relative frequency of each trend.
What changes should I make in my code??

```
[Here is my data][1]][1]
```

[image]

```
plt.pie(data['Day_Per_Change'],labels=data['Trend'])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your column with amounts seems to contain negative numbers. That doesn't work for matplotlib's pie chart.  Also, when the sum is smaller than one, matplotlib will interpret the values as fractions, only filling part of the circle. You can use `plt.pie(data['Day_Per_Change']*100,...)` to work around that behavior. If you have more than 20 slices, it is hard to have distinguishable colors.

Comment: Could you add the output of `print(list(data['Day_Per_Change']))` as text (not as image) to your post? That way it is easier to have a reproducible example.

Comment: pie charts only really work when you have a few categories (i.e. <8, and barely only then or at all).  you probably want to use something like `groupby` on the `Trend` and aggregate the values appropriately

Comment: A bar chart or a line plot seem to be more appropriate to visualize this type of data.